# How to work with Collection of related entities in SpringData?

Tags: spring, orm, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm quite new to data-related technologies and I'm struggling with many questions. My code is related to Spring Data Neo4j, but I think the question can likely be related to other frameworks also (like the JPA implementations).

For the sake of simplicity, suppose that I have two related entities

```
 @NodeEntity public class A { @RelatedTo Set<B> bs /* Other fields, getters and setters*/ }
 @NodeEntity public class B { @RelatedTo A a; /* Other fields, getters and setters*/}
```

two @Repository to access them

```
@Repositoty 
public interface ARepository extends CRUDRepository<A> { /* The usual methods based on name */ }
@Repositoty 
public interface BRepository extends CRUDRepository<B> { /* The usual methods based on name */ }
```

and two interface on the service layer

```
@Service
public interface AService { /* Some useful methods such as CRUD operations*/ }
@Service
public interface BService { /* Some useful methods such as CRUD operations*/ }
```

Obviously, these two interfaces have a class that implement the methods for the specific database used (in this case, `AServiceNeo4j` and `BServiceNeo4j`)

---

Ok, after all these boilerplate code, here are the real questions:

1. First of all, where do I have to initialize `bs`? I've seen many people do it directly in the POJO class, when declaring the field (`private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();`). Is it a good solution? Doesn't it have negative influences on performance? More generally, what are the pro and cons of this solution instead of, for example, do it on the `@Service` classes (like my code below)?
2. In order to add an element to the set, should I always fetch the whole set, then invoke an add on it and finally store/update the entity? Or is there a more concise way that avoid to load the whole set in memory?
3. Does it make sense to have an `addB()` method on my service layer (again, like my example below)? I've not seen this solution yet; instead in some example I've seen this method declared directly inside POJO classes (so an `addB(B b)` method). In other examples, I've seen no `addB()` method at all; instead, the business logic simply invokes `a.getBs().add(new B())`. What is the best solution and why?

My proposed solution is something like that

```
@Service
public class AServiceNeo4j 
{
    /* The other usual methods based on name */ 
    public void addB(A a, B b)
    {
        // Start transaction, start try block
        if (a.getBs() == null)
            a.setBs(new HashSet<B>() );
        a.getBs().add(b);
        // Store a, add catch and finally blocks
    }
}
```

So, from my business logic, I can do this:

```
A a = new A();
AService aService = // get the service bean from the applicationContext
aService.create(a);
B b = new B();
aService.addB(a, b);
```

as opposed to

```
A a = new A();
AService aService = // get the service bean from the applicationContext
aService.create(a);
B b = new B();
a.getB(s).add(b); // To work, the set should be instantiated in the POJO class (see point 1)
aService.update(a);
```

What are the advantages of both solutions? What is the suggested way?

Also, with both solutions, the objects aren't automatically update by the framework. What I mean is that, for the first solution, invoking `a.getBs().size()` returns 0 (or null, depending on the implementation of the POJO class). The same issue happen for the second solution invoking `b.getA()`,

For these methods to work properly, I have to retrieve the local object from the datastore to have the updated value. Something like

```
a = aService.find(a); // or aService.fetch(a);
a.getBs().size();
```

or

```
b = bService.find(b); // or bService.fetch(b);
b.getA();
```

Why is this? Shouldn't it be done automatically by the underlying framework? If not, is this the standard way to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning where to initialize the Collection, I've adopted as a good    practise to do it in the `@NodeEntity` when field is declared    (`private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>();`) There are some examples of    spring-data-neo4j where is done in this way. See [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples/cineasts/src/main/java/org/neo4j/cineasts/domain/Director.java).

To add an element to the `Collection`, you could consider to add a method in the same POJO to do that. Example (keep in mind that set is already initialized)

```
@NodeEntity
public class A {

   @RelatedTo
   Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();

   public void addB(B b) {
      bs.add(b);
   }
}
```

So, in your service layer, you directly could find entity `A` and then    add it `B`.

And then, if you want the framework able to fetch collections automatically, you need to add the annotation `@Fetch`, in addition to `@Related`. Example:

```
   @Fetch
   @RelatedTo
   Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();
```

Good question for those who are starting with spring-data-neo4j. I've been also struggling with questions like these. I'll be waiting for more answers, hoping others can share their experience.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Well, the thing that stopped me from adding the add method in the POJO (or JabaBean, fwiw) is that in this way it simply ceases to be a POJO. OTOH, the thing that stopped me from directly initialize the collections is a potential negative side effect on performance. What do you think about those points?

Comment: I had exactly your same doubts.,. but finally I adopted it, because in my uses case the initialization in the POJO didn't affect to much to the performance (majoriry reads). Anyway, I'll be waiting for other responses. Thanks